# inline part of a list with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

It is possible to inline part of a list with flex box? Here is what I have tried...

The HTML

```html
<ul>
  <li>Connect With Me</li>
  <li>Facebook</li>
  <li>Twitter</li>
  <li>LinkedIn</li>
</ul>
```

The CSS

```css
ul {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

/*obviously does not work, but hopefully gets my point across*/
ul li:not(:first-child) {
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

So the end result is

```
Connect With Me 
Facebook    Twitter    LinkedIn
```

Comment: What do you mean by inline _part_ of the list? You want the first child to be one line, then the 3 spread evenly under it?

Comment: Like this? https://paste.pics/f9583d2a385aecc65eb7ff3ae2deffdd

Comment: https://codepen.io/Kxrl/pen/zYBvZmw how about this, if it solves your issue let me know and I'll write a proper answer

Comment: Yes that is what works for me.  Thanks

Comment: Perfect, I've submitted an answer, if you could please mark it as the answer for future people, would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex wrapping to do this. Setting the first list element to 100% width and enabling wrapping causes it to fill the full top line and wrap the other elements down below. Then, setting the remaining list elements as `flex: 1;` makes them all share the remaining space evenly between them.

Below is a snippet, along with a CodePen demonstrating this behaviour.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  /* just to make it look cleaner */
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li:first-of-type {
  width: 100%;
}

li:not(:first-of-type) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- background just on li's so they stand out -->
<ul>
  <li style="background: red;">Connect With Me</li>
  <li style="background: aqua;">Facebook</li>
  <li style="background: green;">Twitter</li>
  <li style="background: yellow;">LinkedIn</li>
</ul>
```

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/Kxrl/pen/zYBvZmw